# Two full page columns in container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Now I can do this quite easily using `pseudo` elements, but I would like to pass the `background: url('...');` through inline styles as the background images will be dynamic. This would be relatively easy but I would like the right and left column's content to be in a container. (**See snippet below**)

Here's my solution

```css
.colBackgrounds {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.colBackgrounds .container {
  border-left: 1px dashed white;
  border-right: 1px dashed white;
}

.colBackgrounds:before, .colBackgrounds:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute; 
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.colBackgrounds:before {
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

.colBackgrounds:after {
  left: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid colBackgrounds">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          This is the content for the left column
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          This is the content for the right column
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to make the red column and blue column have seperate background images.

Thank you in advance for the help, hopefully someone will have a tidy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my final solution is probably the best I'm going to be able to come up with.
I made a custom class for a half container which can be nested inside of a:

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- This is where you would put your container/halfContainer -->
        ...

    </div>
</div>
```

Check out the pen [here](https://codepen.io/haldencollier/pen/bGbWevV?editors=1100)

Feel free to give me ways on which I can improve this further.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a solution that would allow for inline `background: url('...');`, it's a bit messy but it works.

```css
.pageSplit {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}

.pageSplit .container {
    border-left: 1px dashed white;
    border-right: 1px dashed white;
}

.colBackground {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.colBackground:nth-child(2) {
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row pageSplit">
        <div class="col-6 colBackground" style="background: red;"></div>
        <div class="col-6 colBackground" style="background: blue;"></div>
        <div class="container section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    CONTENT
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    CONTENT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

well you can't access `pseudo` elements from inline style instead you can do it like this:

```css
.colBackgrounds {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.colBackgrounds .container {
  border-left: 1px dashed white;
  border-right: 1px dashed white;
}

.back{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute; 
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

 .back.left{
  left: 0;
}

.back.right{
  left: 50%;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  .back{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
  }
  .back.right{
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    transfrom:translateY(-50%);
  }
   .back.left{
     top:0;
     left:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid colBackgrounds">
 <div class="back right" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/607/900/900')"></div>
   <div class="back left"style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/609/900/900')"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          This is the content for the left column
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          This is the content for the right column
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

replace `pseudo` elements with 2 `divs` and apply dynamic css to them!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I actually posted the same answer. Only thing is, this doesn't work very well responsively.

Comment: That doesn't work how you think would, try it yourself. Those 2 `div`'s use `position: absolute`.

Comment: @HaldenCollier edited post for responsive check it out!

Comment: This is very close to what I need, however, what happens when the column on the left has more text than the right. The height isn't being calculated by the children but the parent, which is not quite what I need.

Comment: I came up with my own solution, which works perfectly for responsiveness! https://codepen.io/haldencollier/pen/bGbWevV?editors=1100